# ClassNotFoundException for Ebean only in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, ebean

I keep getting following exceptions when I run a Spring Application from IntelliJ

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>   com/avaje/ebean/bean/EntityBean   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)   at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247)
>     ... 32 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 51 common
>   frames omitted

however, if I try to run the jar from command line, it works fine.  I turned on the Enhance Beans plugin. not even sure what could be the problem.

Comment: is there more to the stacktrace that leads into your code file?

Answer (score 1):

turns out my Ebean enhancement plugin is in mismatched version, upgraded to latest version and it is all working again.

Comment: don't forget to rebuild the project